# Python/Pandas - How to assign value for each row which depends on cells values

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame like this:

```
  x  y   z
0 AA BB  CC
1 BB NaN CC
2 BB AA  NaN
```

and dictionary:

```
d = {'AA': 1, 'BB': 2, 'CC': 3}
```

I want to compare values from each cell with values from dictionary and add another new column with sum of these values for each row. In result I need something like this:

```
  x  y   z   sum
0 AA BB  CC   6
1 BB NaN CC   5
2 BB AA  NaN  3
```

I need the most efficient solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) per row by `axis=1`, last convert to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print (df.replace(d))
   x    y    z
0  1  2.0  3.0
1  2  NaN  3.0
2  2  1.0  NaN

df['sum'] = df.replace(d).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
    x    y    z  sum
0  AA   BB   CC    6
1  BB  NaN   CC    5
2  BB   AA  NaN    3
```

Comment: First part works, but when i want to sum up values in results I have 0 for each row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, so `print (df.replace(d))` return `DataFrame` with numbers? what is `print (df.replace(d).dtypes)` ?

Comment: And also what return `print (df.replace(d).sum(axis=1))` - all values are 0 or some floats?

Comment: 1. Yes 'print(df.replace(d))' return 'DataFrame' with numbers. 2. Type is 'object'. 3. All values are '0.0'.

Comment: Works fine.I missed one key in my dictionary.